# Remove accents from string in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

When trying to remove all accents from a string in Oracle using the techniques described in this stackoverflow answer: [how replace accented letter in a varchar2 column in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837263/how-replace-accented-letter-in-a-varchar2-column-in-oracle) I’m getting mixed results.

```
select CONVERT('JUAN ROMÄN', 'US7ASCII') from dual;
```

Returns the original string but replaces characters with for example ñ by a question mark (probably because of the chosen charset - tests with different charsets led to different results).

Using the following technique:

```
select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(nlssort(NAME_USER, 'nls_sort=binary_ai')) from YOUR_TABLE;
```

Returns the complete string but also places a NUL value at the end of the string.

Is there a characterset that I can use with Spanish accents to get a correct result (the original string with the different accents removed); is there a way to avoid the NUL value in the utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2 technique?

Based on the comments the the replace char(0) seems to remove the NUL value. For example

```
select
   upper(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort('this is áà ñew test','nls_sort=binary_ai')))) as test,
   replace(upper(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort('this is áà ñew test','nls_sort=binary_ai')))),chr(0),'') as test2
from dual;
```

If possible I would however to have a more 'straightforward/simpler' solution.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do you have a problem with character display?

Comment: With your second method, can't you just remove the nul (`chr(0)`)?

Comment: There are no issues in the display. It is a specific requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `TRANSLATE(your_string, from_chars, to_chars)` https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions196.htm

Just put all chars with accents in `from_chars` string and their corresponding replacement chars in `to_chars`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the following page: https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/how-to-do-case-insensitive-and-accent-insensitive-search-in-oracle-database

```
select substr ( athlete_name, instr ( athlete_name, ', ' ) + 2 ) given_names, athlete_name from olym_athletes where athlete_name like '%helene%' Collate binary_ai order by given_names;
```

Using the collate `binary_ai`, and filters without uppercase and lowercase, and also the accents I hope you serve another example:

```
SELECT id, name, surname, salary FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE SURNAME LIKE '%PeRéZ%' Collate binary_ai ;
```