# Strip non English characters in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, character-set

I'm working on a system that records persons names. We need to strip accents from the names to suit legacy systems. One such fictionalised example is RÃOUL TÉLITINO and we need to convert Ã to A and É to E and so forth.
 
I'm having difficulty doing so.
 
**Information**:

```
SELECT *
  FROM v$nls_parameters
WHERE parameter LIKE '%CHARACTERSET'
```

Gives

```
**Parameter**:INLS_CHARACTERSET 
**Value**: AL32UTF8
   and
**Parameter**: NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET     **Value**: AL16UTF16|
```

What I have tried:

#### Collate

```
select 'RÃOUL TÉLITINO' collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS
```

but I get

> ORA-12746: unrecognied collation name
> "SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1251_CS_AS"

#### `CONVERT()`

First try

```
select CONVERT('JUAN ROMÄN', 'US7ASCII') from dual;
```

Gives the desirable `'JUAN ROMAN'`, but

```
select CONVERT('RÃOUL TÉRK', 'US7ASCII') from dual;
```

misses the `Ã`, viz: `R?OUL TERK`.

second try

Other parameters I've tried are `AL16UTF16` (but this doesn't change the input string) and `AL16UTF16`, `AL24UTFFSS`, `AL32UTF8`, but these convert to Chinese characters.

Comment: I wouldn't do this entirely in SQL because SQL is not a text-processing system. Personally, I'd write a utility script in Linqpad or similar that performs the text transformation using a dedicated text processing library and then issues a batch `UPDATE`.

Comment: `SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS` is an MS SQL Server collation name, not an Oracle collation name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove accents from string in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53019511/remove-accents-from-string-in-oracle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried Translate() ?

```
translate(text,
'ÂÃÄÀÁÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝŸàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ',
'AAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOOUUUUYYaaaaaaceeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyy')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [translate](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/translate.php) function, it replaces a sequence of characters in a string with another set of characters, by replacing single character at a time.

e.g.

```
select translate(WORD,'ÃÉÄ','ΑΕA') from dual
```

or on your own example

```
select translate('JUAN ROMÄN', 'ÃÄ','AA') from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Translate you can also make use of Regular expression.Below post maybe helpful for you.

[Finding and removing non ascii characters from an Oracle Varchar2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236475/finding-and-removing-non-ascii-characters-from-an-oracle-varchar2)