# Remove accent/special characters in columns in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

Is there anyway we can remove the accent in columns?

Example: `per_names` table has following column names:

```
Name
Arévalo
Chère
```

I want this column to have values as follows:

```
Name
    Arevalo
    Chere
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove accents from string in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53019511/remove-accents-from-string-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the translate command..

```
TRANSLATE(data,'ÁÉáéÑ','AEaeN')
```

That will map: Á to A, É to E, á to a, é to e, Ñ to N. Just keep adding the characters you need to map more