# Is there a Oracle SQL Function that TRANSLATEs or REPLACEs localized characters with basic ones?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I know about TRANSLATE & REPLACE, but I want to know if there is a function that does the conversion from **any** language letter to the 26 English letters **without** the need to specify the equivalences.

This is, the hypothetical function should know that "ä" is either "ae" or "a" without me having to write the specific TRANSLATE query:

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('Hände', 'ä', 'a') FROM DUAL;
```

Which would end up with me having to write a lengthy query for each equivalence, or having to write a DB Function just for that.

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('Hände', 'äëöåßñç', 'aeoasnc') FROM DUAL;
```

Furthermore, if there is a chance to get better equivalences (e.g. "ss" instead of "ß", or "oe" instead of "ö"), it would be better.

This is because I will perform several conversions for several strings & with several equivalences (some of them I might not know beforehand).

Comment: You can do it in java, so it might be done with a stored procedure: [`java.text.Normalizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html), decompose text in latin letter + accent, and then replace the accents with empty string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how replace accented letter in a varchar2 column in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837263/how-replace-accented-letter-in-a-varchar2-column-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want Greek and alike characters to be replace by ?, you could also merge both results like this:

```
WITH data(cvt,str) AS
(
    SELECT CONVERT(TRANSLATE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('ÀÂÄäàáâãăāåąæčçðďéèëêěĕėęğģġîĭïīìíłļľŀñńňņöóòôõσøřśŝšşţüúùûǔųūůŵýÿżźžżαβßγδεζŋηικλμµνξπρσςτυφω', 'Æ', 'AE'),
        'æ', 'ae' ),
        'ß', 'ss' ),
        'Þ', 'TH' ),
        'þ', 'th' ), 'Ã;ÅÐÑÕØãåðñõø', 'AADNOOaadnoo'), 'US7ASCII', 'UTF8') AS cvt,
        REPLACE(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(NLSSORT('ÀÂÄäàáâãăāåąæčçðďéèëêěĕėęğģġîĭïīìíłļľŀñńňņöóòôõσøřśŝšşţüúùûǔųūůŵýÿżźžżαβßγδεζŋηικλμµνξπρσςτυφω', 'nls_sort=binary_ai')), CHR(0), '') 
    as stripped
    FROM DUAL
)
SELECT LISTAGG(res,'') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY lvl) AS cvt FROM (
    SELECT LEVEL AS lvl, DECODE(substr(cvt,level,1),'?',substr(str,level,1),substr(cvt,level,1)) AS res
    FROM data
    CONNECT BY level <= length(cvt) 
)
;
 -- result: AAAaaaaaaadaaeccndeeeeeeeeggiiiiiiilllnonnooooooorsssstuuuuuuuuwyyzzzzαβssγδεζŋηικλμμνξπρσστυφω
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you try `utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort(s, 'nls_sort=binary_ai')))` ?

Comment: or
SELECT CONVERT(TRANSLATE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(str, 'Æ', 'AE'),
        'æ', 'ae' ),
        'ß', 'ss' ),
        'Þ', 'TH' ),
        'þ', 'th' ), 'Ã;ÅÐÑÕØãåðñõø', 'AADNOOaadnoo'), 'US7ASCII', 'UTF8')
FROM DUAL
;

Comment: Thank you, I think I can use a combination of BINARY_AI or CONVERT (US7ASCII) with manual TRANSLATE for more complex characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can  convert this to 7 bit ASCII:

```
SELECT CONVERT('Hände', 'US7ASCII') FROM dual;
```

(Not all special characters can properly converted, though. See this demo https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e222a42f3241a53859f2193d317d710a where ø results in a mere questionmark.)

Comment: Thanks, I did try it & noticed the same. Special characters like in Swedish, Norwegian, Danish, German & Spanish will return a question mark to me. It would not help, as there are addresses that require them.

Comment: Yep. I think the best way to handle this would be to write a function converting letter by letter. Thus you can replace 'ä' by 'ae' for instance, so it doesn't get mutilated. This would also properly deal with 'ß' becoming 'ss'. You can even create a conversion table for this. And you can raise an exception when the function gets confronted with a letter it does not yet know.